# Prestashop How to export multiple invoice selected orders in a single pdf

Tags: pdf, export, prestashop, invoice

How can I add an option to the "Bulk actions" button that allows exporting of all the selected orders invoice in a single pdf?

The option of exporting the invoices does not work for me, since I have to filter it by customer group and I cannot go one by one either.

Attachment capture

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to override (or modify) `AdminOrdersController`, look at this file and how it's done for order state update, you have an array of bulk actions:

```
$this->bulk_actions = array(
            'updateOrderStatus' => array('text' => $this->l('Change Order Status'), 'icon' => 'icon-refresh')
        );
```

if you add something to this array, it will be available from this drop-down menu, a key is an action name for it, if you want to process order status change you need to use this code (for example in postProcess method), submitBulk is a standard prefix for all those actions. submitBulkYOUR_ARRAY_KEY, little snippet:

```
if (Tools::isSubmit('submitBulkupdateOrderStatus'.$this->table)) {
// your code
}
```

I hope this helps you understand how does it work. If you have more questions let me know.

If you want to understand how to generate multiple PDF at once, look at the `AdminPdfController`, you can look at this file from 1.6 version of PrestaShop

Comment: Thanks, I bought one module for this, but you help is important for me for future changes.

Comment: That worked perfectly up to 1.7.6.9 but in 1.7.7.0 the Orders page has been migrated to the new structure.
Could you let us know how to do the same from 1.7.7.0? I've tried myself, adding a new bulk action from a custom module is simple but I'm stuck on how to add the new submit_route.

Comment: This is more complex topic, you need to extend Orders Grid component, more informations here: https://devdocs.prestashop.com/1.7/development/components/grid/tutorials/work-with-bulk-actions/